Prolog: Compress a list that contains segments of continuous numbers to a list which contains list of range of segments [start,end]
I'm new in prolog and I'm trying to solve this exercise but I can not get my desired output.Compressing a list of integers to a compressed list. List contains segments of continuous integers.A segment with length greater than 2 will be encoded to list [start, end], end is inclusive. If the length is not greater than 2 will be kept no change.
Sample:
compress([3,4,6,7,8,9,10,15,16,17,20,22,23,24,25], CompressedList).
CompressedList = [3, 4, [6,10],[15, 17],20, [22,25]].
My incorrect output:
CompressedList = [[3, [4]], [6,[10]],[15, [17]],20, [22,[25]]].
My code is:
compress([], []).

compress([X], [X]).

compress([X, Y | T], [X | CompressedTail]) :-
    X + 1 =\= Y,
    compress([Y | T], CompressedTail).
    
    
compress([X, Y | T], [[X, YLast] | CompressedTail]) :-
    compress_consecutive([Y | T], YLast, Next),
    compress(Next, CompressedTail).


compress_consecutive([], Last, []) :- Last = [].
compress_consecutive([X], [X], []) :- !.
compress_consecutive([X, Y | T], Last, Next) :-
    X + 1 =:= Y,
    compress_consecutive([Y | T], Last, Next).
    
    
compress_consecutive([X, Y | T], [X], [Y | T]) :- X + 1 =\= Y. ```


@lurker: could  you help me?

@TessellatingHeckler: could  you help me?

(I didn't get that message - I think Stackoverflow doesn't notify unless the person has already commented or answered)

%compress/2 predicate
% Base case
compress([], []).

% Base case
compress([X], [X]).

compress([X, Y | T], [X | CompressedTail]) :-
    X + 1 =\= Y,
    compress([Y | T], CompressedTail).
    
compress([X, Y, Z| T], [X, Y| CompressedTail]) :-
    X + 1 =:= Y,
    Y + 1 =\= Z,
    compress([Z | T], CompressedTail).
    
    
compress([X, Y | T], [[X, YLast] | CompressedTail]) :-
    compress_consecutive([Y | T], YLast, Next),
    compress(Next, CompressedTail).

% Helper predicate to find the last element of a consecutive segment.
compress_consecutive([], Last, []) :- Last = [].
compress_consecutive([X], X, []) :- !.
compress_consecutive([X, Y | T], Last, Next) :-
    X + 1 =:= Y,
    compress_consecutive([Y | T], Last, Next).
    
    
compress_consecutive([X, Y | T], X, [Y | T]) :- 
X + 1 =\= Y.


Can use DCG phrase:
% Provides eos//0
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

% End of string
inc_succ --> eos, !.
% Placing into the Remainder string, as "push-back"
inc_succ, [[First, Last]] -->
    inc_comp(First, Last),
    !,
    inc_succ.
% No change
inc_succ, [Next] --> [Next],
    inc_succ.

inc_comp(First, Last) --> [First],
    inc_comp_(First, Last, 1, Len),
    {   Len > 2 }.

inc_comp_(Prev, Last, Len0, Len) --> [Next],
    {   Next is Prev + 1,
        Len1 is Len0 + 1
    },
    !,
    inc_comp_(Next, Last, Len1, Len).
% Ending is the final choice, to process "greedily"
inc_comp_(Last, Last, Len, Len) --> [].

Result in swi-prolog:
?- phrase(inc_succ, [1,2,4,5,6,9,10,11,12,13,18,19], R).
R = [1, 2, [4, 6], [9, 13], 18, 19].

